# Interface for Lazy Loaded List of Objects

Tags: java, list, rest, interface, lazy-loading

We have a whole bunch of data sources where we consult some REST API or other and get back a list of objects. I'm trying to design an abstraction layer that doesn't need to know how to contact any specific API instance or how to semantically interpret the objects, but that guarantees that we get back a list of objects from whichever class implements the interface we need at the time.

I expect at times the numbers of results to be quite large (but always finite!) and often slow to retrieve, so I require something that does not load everything into memory all at once but allows the results of the list to be worked with as they become available. I'm fine if the list blocks on `next` or `hasNext` or whatever the appropriate analogue is.

What's the most appropriate abstraction / approach for achieving these goals and how is it implemented?

My gut tells me it ought to be some flavor of Java 8 Streams, possibly created via the Java 9 `Stream.iterate` method, but I'm not too familiar with functional programming paradigms and can't for the life of me figure out how one would populate the elements of the Stream as they became available from the REST calls and close it out when it's finished.

Comment: What about a simple `Iterator`? Probably easier to get up and running quickly

Comment: Yup. `Iterator` sounds good. Or if you want to get into [reactive programming](https://projectreactor.io/learn), you could use a `Flux`.

Comment: As I work through it further, I think the problem I'm having is how to I get an Iterator that is populated in the background. My current suspicious now involve a Queue of sorts and a separate thread; it's very likely that I'm conflating a couple of unrelated problems and that's where the confusion is setting in.

Comment: You could create a LinkedList and add to it every time someone calls next()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I was confusing myself by conflating two issues: how to provide an Iterator in an Interface (which is trivial), and how to populate that Iterator in the background. I ended up with roughly the following:

Create a custom abstract class which implements Iterator. That class has an internal BlockingQueue and an internal List. It also defines an abstract method which is intended to perform all the activities of population in a single invocation.

The first time `hasNext()` is called, kick off a daemon thread which invokes that abstract method. Then, while the thread is alive (meaning it's still populating the BlockingQueue) or the List isn't empty (meaning not all elements have been consumed via `next()`), poll against the BlockingQueue until it has at least one element in it. Once it does, remove that element and add it to the List. `next()` merely returns elements from the List.

This results in lazy loading (nothing occurs until `hasNext()` is called for the first time) that also happens asynchronously in the background -- the caller will be able to process things as soon as they're available (`hasNext()` will block if things aren't available), and it doesn't use up an unreasonable amount of memory (the BlockingQueue will block if it has too many elements).